Is possible that a button that has focus and click again on it clear its focus, using just css?
I want to make a focused button lose its focus after being clicked again. To illustrate, I want to click at the red button and it will become blue, then click again on it and it become red again.
import styled from "styled-components";

const Button = styled.button`
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;

    &:focus {
        background-color: blue;
    }
`;

export default function ButtonFocus() {
    return <Button>Button</Button>;
}


I know how to make it with javascript, but i'm triyng to make it using just css (styled component in that case, just to keep it on the same page).

try experimenting :active state

Perhaps style a checkbox instead of a button? Use the checked property.

Are you able to change the HTML (i.e. does it have to be a button element)?

Do you want it to keep the blue color if it loses focus e.g. because the user clicked elsewhere?


i want to click at the red button and it will become blue, than click again on it and it become red again.

Yes, you can achieve this effect.
You'll need to include two :focus-able child elements within the <button>.
Think about the following:

If you apply the attribute tabindex="0" you can make any element :focus-able.
If you apply the style pointer-events: none you can make any element unresponsive to clicks (and, thus, unable to receive focus from user-interaction)
If you apply the style opacity: 0 you can render any element invisible (or completely transparent, at any rate)

Consequently, if you give your <button> two :focusable <span> child-elements, you can, via CSS, alternate each <span> between the two following states:

visible (opacity: 1) but unresponsive to clicks (pointer-events: none)
responsive to clicks (pointer-events: auto) but invisible (opacity: 0)


Working Example:


button {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.layer1,
.layer2 {
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
}

.layer1 {
  background-color: red;
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.layer2 {
  background-color: blue;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: auto;
}

.layer1:focus,
.layer2:focus {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: none;
}
<button type="button">
  <span class="layer1" tabindex="0"></span>
  <span class="layer2" tabindex="0"></span>
</button>




Isn't this invalid HTML - divs inside a button, and changing won't help as focusable elements not allowed inside a button.

You make a good point, @AHaworth - the child elements of the <button> should be <span>, not <div>. I'm not sure there is anything to be done about the other issue.

you can try below code
import styled from "styled-components";

const Button = styled.button`
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;

    &:focus {
        background-color: blue;
    }

    &:active {
        outline: none; /* Remove the focus outline */
    }
`;

export default function ButtonFocus() {
    return <Button>Button</Button>;
}

